# TypeScript Objects as Dictionary types as in C#

Tags: arrays, object, dictionary, typescript

I have some JavaScript code that uses objects as dictionaries; for example a 'person' object will hold a some personal details keyed off the email address.

```
var people = {<email> : <'some personal data'>};

adding   > "people[<email>] = <data>;" 
getting  > "var data = people[<email>];" 
deleting > "delete people[<email>];"
```

Is it possible to describe this in Typescript? or do I have to use an Array?

Comment: Old post but note that there is the ES6 Map

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30019542/6908282

Answer (score 616, accepted):

In newer versions of typescript you can use:

```
type Customers = Record<string, Customer>
```

In older versions you can use:

```
var map: { [email: string]: Customer; } = { };
map['foo@gmail.com'] = new Customer(); // OK
map[14] = new Customer(); // Not OK, 14 is not a string
map['bar@hotmail.com'] = 'x'; // Not OK, 'x' is not a customer
```

You can also make an interface if you don't want to type that whole type annotation out every time:

```
interface StringToCustomerMap {
    [email: string]: Customer;
}

var map: StringToCustomerMap = { };
// Equivalent to first line of above
```

Comment: That's a useful way to make sure that the compiler restricts indexes to strings. Interesting. Doesn't look like you can specify the index type to be anything other than strings or integers, but that makes sense, since it just maps to the native JS object indexes.

Comment: You may know this, but there are also some potential gotchas with this approach, the big one being that there's no safe and easy way to iterate through all the members. This code, for instance, shows that `map` contains two members:

 (<any>Object.prototype).something = function(){};
 
 class Customer{}
 
 var map: { [email: string]: Customer; } = { };
 map['foo@gmail.com'] = new Customer();
 
 for (var i in map){
  console.log(map[i])
 }

Comment: how do you remove from it?

Comment: Another interesting approach is:  
    interface MapStringTo<T> {
      [key:string]:T;
    }  
And the declare the variable like `var map:MapStringTo<Customer> = {};`

Comment: @KenSmith The only gotcha comes if somebody changes `Object.prototype`. This technique works great.

Comment: "map[14] = new Customer(); // Not OK, 14 is not a string", doesn't work in typescript rc1, it doesn't give me a error, it just compiles.

Comment: Take note that the index constraint no longer works. [Read more.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3150)

Comment: @TDaver The entries are added as object properties, so you can remove them using the delete keyword.

Comment: You should use the new ES6 `Map` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: this Map looks like a god send but its really a disaster to work with. iterating over keys or values is a nightmare, and if server sends a regular object it is not recognized as a Map.

Comment: First note is I would no longer call it Map, since that is a keyword now in ES6, I call it dictionary. Second is I got stuck for a while on iterating and then started using the Object.keys(dictionary) and then you can do any iterating fun you want, such as .map() and .filter().

Comment: I prefer `[email: string]: Customer` over `Record<string, Customer>` because the "email: string" part captures more intent about what the _meaning_ of the key is, not just its type.

Answer (score 157):

In addition to using an map-*like* object, there has been an actual [`Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for some time now, which is available in TypeScript when compiling to ES6, or when using a polyfill with the ES6 [type-definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/es6-shim):

```
let people = new Map<string, Person>();
```

It supports the same functionality as `Object`, and more, with a slightly different syntax:

```
// Adding an item (a key-value pair):
people.set("John", { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" });

// Checking for the presence of a key:
people.has("John"); // true

// Retrieving a value by a key:
people.get("John").lastName; // "Doe"

// Deleting an item by a key:
people.delete("John");
```

This alone has several advantages over using a map-*like* object, such as:

- Support for non-string based keys, e.g. numbers or objects, neither of which are supported by `Object` (no, `Object` does not support numbers, it converts them to strings)
- Less room for errors when not using `--noImplicitAny`, as a `Map` always has a *key* type and a *value* type, whereas an object *might* not have an index-signature
- The functionality of adding/removing items (key-value pairs) is optimized for the task, [unlike creating properties on an `Object`](https://ariya.io/2012/02/javascript-object-structure-speed-matters)

Additionally, a `Map` object provides a more powerful and elegant API for common tasks, most of which are not available through simple `Object`s without hacking together helper functions (although some of these require a full ES6 iterator/iterable polyfill for ES5 targets or below):

```
// Iterate over Map entries:
people.forEach((person, key) => ...);

// Clear the Map:
people.clear();

// Get Map size:
people.size;

// Extract keys into array (in insertion order):
let keys = Array.from(people.keys());

// Extract values into array (in insertion order):
let values = Array.from(people.values());
```

Comment: Thats awesome! But sadly it got wrong serialized using `JSON.stringify()`, so it can be used e.g. for socket.io :(

Comment: @Lion -- well yes, `Map` serialization is rather funny. I, for one, perform a conversion to key-value-pair objects before serializing, and then back (e.g. object of `{ key: "John", value: { firstName: "John" } }`).

Comment: I made the mistake of using a map instead of a plain old object, and the serialization really got me. Steer clear in my opinion.

Comment: This is beautiful. So glad you inspired me to finally dip into maps. This will pretty much replace my usual keymap/dictionary structures since it's so much easier to strongly type the keys.

Comment: yeah maps aren't always the greatest choice, say for example you wanted to get a key but case insensitive. Not possible.

Answer (score 83):

You can use templated interfaces like this:

```
interface Map<T> {
    [K: string]: T;
}

let dict: Map<number> = {};
dict["one"] = 1;
```

Comment: Note that this collides with the es6 Map type. Better than the other answer because the index constraint is ignored.

Comment: I use Dictionary instead of Map to avoid confusion, and you can use the literal object notation: `let dict: Dictionary<number> = { "one": 1, "two": 2 };`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Record` for this:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt

Example (A mapping between AppointmentStatus enum and some meta data):

```
  const iconMapping: Record<AppointmentStatus, Icon> = {
    [AppointmentStatus.Failed]: { Name: 'calendar times', Color: 'red' },
    [AppointmentStatus.Canceled]: { Name: 'calendar times outline', Color: 'red' },
    [AppointmentStatus.Confirmed]: { Name: 'calendar check outline', Color: 'green' },
    [AppointmentStatus.Requested]: { Name: 'calendar alternate outline', Color: 'orange' },
    [AppointmentStatus.None]: { Name: 'calendar outline', Color: 'blue' }
  }
```

Now with interface as value:

`interface Icon {
  Name: string
  Color: string
}`

Usage:

`const icon: SemanticIcon = iconMapping[appointment.Status]`

Comment: This is very useful. Would you use a string `enum` or a `class/object` for `AppointmentStatus` - or does it matter?

Comment: @Drenai doesn't matter, it's what you prefer

Comment: I figured it out myself, to use enum in a record before I have found this answer. the main benefit is that it enforces exhaustiveness check. means none of the keys from enum can be skipped. none keys not included in enum can be added. this is a dictionary with run-type check

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the Record type in typescript :

```
export interface nameInterface { 
    propName : Record<string, otherComplexInterface> 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Lodash has a simple Dictionary implementation and has good TypeScript support

Install Lodash:

```
npm install lodash @types/lodash --save
```

Import and usage:

```
import { Dictionary } from "lodash";
let properties : Dictionary<string> = {
    "key": "value"        
}
console.log(properties["key"])
```