# Translate JsObject into TypeScript Object

Tags: c#, typescript

I have to translate `C#` app into `TypeScript`. It goes pretty well, but I have a problem with that:

```
private SharpKit.JavaScript.JsObject<JsString, JsBoolean> _changedLayers = new SharpKit.JavaScript.JsObject<JsString, JsBoolean>();
```

Does anyone know how to convert this?

**[edit]**
Ok, I guess I should do something like this:

```
private _changedLayers: (String, Boolean) => Object;
```

But now I wonder how to initialize this object? I tried this, but doesn't work...

```
this._changedLayers = { String: new String(), Boolean: new Boolean() };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var _changedLayers : { [key: string]: bool; } = {};

_changedLayers['foo'] = true; // ok
_changedLayers[1] = true; // error
_changedLayers['bar'] = 'abc'; // error
```

You could also define an interface:

```
interface StringToBoolMap {
    [key: string]: bool;
}

var _changedLayers : StringToBoolMap = {};
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631557/typescript-objects-as-dictionary-types-as-in-c-sharp/13631733#13631733