# ES6 Map in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.5

I'm creating a class in typescript that has a property that is an ES6 (ECMAscript 2016) Map like so:

```
class Item {
  configs: ????;
  constructor () {
    this.configs = new Map();
  }
}
```

How do I declare an ES6 Map type in typescript?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13631557/6908282

Answer (score 379, accepted):

**EDIT (Jun 5 2019):** While the idea that "TypeScript supports `Map` natively" is still true, since version 2.1 TypeScript supports something called [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

```js
type MyMapLikeType = Record<string, IPerson>;
const peopleA: MyMapLikeType = {
    "a": { name: "joe" },
    "b": { name: "bart" },
};
```

Unfortunately the first generic parameter (key type) is still not fully respected: even with a `string` type, something like `peopleA[0]` (a `number`) is still valid.

---

**EDIT (Apr 25 2016):** The answer below is old and should not be considered the best answer. TypeScript does support Maps "natively" now, so it simply allows ES6 Maps to be used when the output is ES6. For ES5, it does not provide polyfills; you need to embed them yourself.

For more information, refer to [mohamed hegazy's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30112075/439026) for a more modern answer, or even [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/39taz3/map_class_in_typescript/cs69xpj) for a short version.

---

As of 1.5.0 beta, TypeScript does not yet support [Maps](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html). It is not yet part of the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap), either.

The current best solution is an object with typed key and value (sometimes called a hashmap). For an object with keys of type `string`, and values of type `number`:

```
var arr : { [key:string]:number; } = {};
```

Some caveats, however:

1. keys can only be of type `string` or `number`
2. It actually doesn't matter what you use as the key type, since numbers/strings are still accepted interchangeably (only the value is enforced).

With the above example:

```
// OK:
arr["name"] = 1; // String key is fine
arr[0] = 0; // Number key is fine too

// Not OK:
arr[{ a: "a" }] = 2; // Invalid key
arr[3] = "name"; // Invalid value
```

Comment: How then do you iterate the properties in the map? When I do arr.values(), I get "Property 'values' does not exist on type..."

Comment: Not the same as `values()`, I'd do `for (var key in arr) ... arr[key]` or [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Other solution (which is more and more realistic nowadays and will be for a while for a lot of things) is to use [corejs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3956).

Comment: In fact when I use any key as a property on a map declared in this way I get "Property 'whatever' does not exist on type"

Comment: I'm using the map class to build one, but even if I do `map Map<string,string>=new Map<string,string>()` when i do `map.set(something)`  I get an exception `map is undefined`, is there another way to initialize it?

Comment: When targetting ES5, even with polyfills, you can't use certain features - see github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6842

Comment: @novaline no. Map-wise there's no update needed as the way it works (with polyfills for ES5) is party of the core design of TS.

Comment: The Record type was exactly what I needed to replace Map! I had no idea this existed, thank you!!

Answer (score 134):

See comment in: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3069#issuecomment-99964139

> TypeScript does not come with built in pollyfills. it is up to you to
>   decide which pollyfill to use, if any. you can use something like
>   [es6Collection](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections),
>   [es6-shims](https://github.com/es-shims/es6-shim),
>   [corejs](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)..etc. All the Typescript
>   compiler needs is a declaration for the ES6 constructs you want to
>   use. you can find them all in [this lib
>   file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4609).
>
> here is the relevant portion:
>
> ```js
> interface Map<K, V> {
>     clear(): void;
>     delete(key: K): boolean;
>     entries(): IterableIterator<[K, V]>;
>     forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, index: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
>     get(key: K): V;
>     has(key: K): boolean;
>     keys(): IterableIterator<K>;
>     set(key: K, value?: V): Map<K, V>;
>     size: number;
>     values(): IterableIterator<V>;
>     [Symbol.iterator]():IterableIterator<[K,V]>;
>     [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
> }
>
> interface MapConstructor {
>     new <K, V>(): Map<K, V>;
>     new <K, V>(iterable: Iterable<[K, V]>): Map<K, V>;
>     prototype: Map<any, any>;
> }
> declare var Map: MapConstructor;
> ```

Comment: When targetting ES5, even with polyfills, you can't use certain features - see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6842

Answer (score 108):

Here is an example:

```
this.configs = new Map<string, string>();
this.configs.set("key", "value");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qqho9fsn/)

Comment: @Zelphir For your error `TS2304`, please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416691/webpack-ts2304-cannot-find-name-map-set-promise

Answer (score 54):

Yes Map is now available in typescript..  if you look in lib.es6.d.ts, you will see the interface:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
  clear(): void;
  delete(key: K): boolean;
  forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void,thisArg?: any): void;
  get(key: K): V | undefined;
  has(key: K): boolean;
  set(key: K, value: V): this;
  readonly size: number;}
```

Its great to use as a dictionary of string,object pairs.. the only annoyance is that if you are using it to assign values elsewhere with **Map.get(key)** the IDE like Code gives you problems about being possible undefined.. rather than creating a variable with an is-defined check .. simply cast the type (assuming you know for sure the map has the key-value pair)

```
class myclass {
   mymap:Map<string,object>
   ...
   mymap = new Map<string,object>()
   mymap.set("akey",AnObject)
   let objectref = <AnObject>mymap.get("akey")
```

Answer (score 14):

> How do I declare an ES6 Map type in typescript?

You need to target `--module es6`. This is misfortunate and you can raise your concern here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2953#issuecomment-98514111

Answer (score 12):

As a bare minimum:

tsconfig:

```
 "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ]
```

and install a polyfill such as https://github.com/zloirock/core-js if you want IE < 11 support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is official but this worked for me in typescript 2.7.1:

```
class Item {
   configs: Map<string, string>;
   constructor () {
     this.configs = new Map();
   }
}
```

In simple `Map<keyType, valueType>`

Answer (score 4):

With the [lib config option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) your are able to cherry pick Map into your project. Just add `es2015.collection` to your lib section. When you have no lib config add one with [the defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and add `es2015.collection`.

So when you have target: es5, change tsconfig.json to:

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [ "dom", "es5", "scripthost", "es2015.collection" ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript does not yet support `Map`.

[ES6 Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#typescript)

Comment: This page on typescript's wiki seems to say that it is supported: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ECMAScript%206%20Status&referringTitle=Roadmap

Comment: 2019 june - Map is supported

Answer (score 1):

Add `"target": "ESNEXT"` property to the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNEXT" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map inside a Typescript class as follows

```
export class Shop {
  public locations: Map<number, string>;

  constructor() {
   // initialize an empty map
   this.locations= new Map<number,string>();
  }

   // get & set functions
   ........
}
```