# Typescript: use lib.core.es6.d.ts

Tags: compilation, typescript, ecmascript-6, building

I'm using typescript, and trying to use an ES6 map, but getting compile errors.

I've discerned that I need to reference the file `lib.core.es6.d.ts` ([ES6 Map in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript/30112075#30112075)), and I know where that is on my filesystem. However, I can't find anything that specifies what to do to use that file.

Right now, I just have two files in a folder which I'm compiling with 
`tsc --module amd treenode.ts treemerge.ts`

How do I use the es6 types in one of those files? If the answer is "restructure your project the way site X says to", I'll grumble but I guess that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I can't find anything that specifies what to do to use that file.

You need to get that file manually from github AND compile your project with `--noLib` passing in the lib file yourself.

Comment: Like this?

    {
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noLib": true
      },
      "files": [
        "app/*.ts",
        "scripts/lib.es6.d.ts"
      ]
    }

Answer (score 4):

The default build target is targeting `ES5` which then forces the compiler to use the default `lib.core.d.ts`, because it cannot assume that the `ES6` types will be available.

If you set your target to `ES6` the compiler will automatically target the `lib.core.es6.d.ts`, without you having to do that yourself.  This does have the disadvantage that your compiled output will also be `ES6` compliant JavaScript instead of `ES5`.  What that means for example, is that if you use any classes in your TypeScript code, the compiler will output JavaScript classes to the output file.

To get around this, you can either manually change the reference to `lib.core.es6.d.ts` as basarat mentions, or you can add in something like [babel](http://babeljs.io/) that will transpile the `ES6` code to compliant `ES5` code for you automatically.

As an example I've recently moved over `omnisharp-atom` and `omnisharp-client` to target `ES6` and use babel as an additional transpiler to produce `ES5` source files.

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-node-client/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L7-L9
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-atom/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L45-L52
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-node-client/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L54-L61