# webpack TS2304 Cannot find name 'Map', 'Set', 'Promise'

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have the following webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'ng2-auto-complete': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.html']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].umd.js",
    library: ["[name]"],
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  externals: [
    /^rxjs\//,    //.... any other way? rx.umd.min.js does work?
    /^@angular\//
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { // Support for .ts files.
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: [/test/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

and the following tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

When I run `tsc` command as the following, it all works fine.

```
ng2-auto-complete (master)$ tsc --declaration
ng2-auto-complete (master)$
```

When I run `webpack` command, it shows typescript compile errors.

```
ng2-auto-complete (master)$ webpack
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.0.0 and /Users/allen/github/ng2-auto-complete/tsconfig.json
Hash: bd6c50e4b9732c3ffa9d
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 5041ms
                       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    ng2-auto-complete.umd.js  24.4 kB       0  [emitted]  ng2-auto-complete
ng2-auto-complete.umd.js.map  28.4 kB       0  [emitted]  ng2-auto-complete
    + 11 hidden modules

ERROR in /Users/allen/github/ng2-auto-complete/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts
(18,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/allen/github/ng2-auto-complete/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts
(96,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/allen/github/ng2-auto-complete/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/worker/location_providers.d.ts
(21,86): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
...
ng2-auto-complete (master)$
```

I don't know what I am missing for webpack and typescript compilation.

`node_modules` has been excluded in `tsconfig.json`

"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],

and type definitions are there in `node_modules`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.31"
```

I also tried to use `typings.json` and typings directory without success.

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160815222444"
  }
}
```

FYI, versions

```
$ node --version
v5.7.1
$ npm --version
3.6.0
$ tsc --version
Version 2.0.0
```

How do I get rid of TS2304 errors with `webpack` command?

Comment: ES6 lib is the only one needed to make it work. In case you are encountering the same problem running typescript with node

Answer (score 128):

I added this to work in `tsconfig.json`, and it seems working without any error.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],  <--- this
    ...
  }
```

I am not sure `lib` are for Typescript 2.0 function or not, but found out there are several libraries are available

From the typescript config schema (note the es2015.collection)

```
 "lib": {
      "description": "Specify library file to be included in the compilation. Requires TypeScript version 2.0 or later.",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [ "es5", "es6", "es2015", "es7", "es2016", "es2017", "dom", "webworker", "scripthost", "es2015.core", "es2015.collection", "es2015.generator", "es2015.iterable",
                    "es2015.promise", "es2015.proxy", "es2015.reflect", "es2015.symbol", "es2015.symbol.wellknown", "es2016.array.include", "es2017.object", "es2017.sharedmemory" ]
      }
    }
```

This solves the compile errors, but I still wonder why `tsc` command works without any errors, but `webpack` does not. `tsc` searches for all possible libraries without using `lib` by `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: you should select your answer as the preferred solution

Comment: Thank you I am Search Guru.Your answer was the best

Answer (score 50):

`Map`, `Set` and `Promise` are `ES6` features.
In your `tsconfig.json` you are using:

```
"target": "es5"
```

This causes the compiler to use the normal [`es5` lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts), which lacks the definitions for the above types.

You want to use the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts):

```
"target": "es6"
```

Comment: Based on [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), target should be 'es5' to generate `es5` code. if target is `es6`, will it still work with lower browser, e.g., 'IE11'?

Comment: No, and not all browsers support the newest es6 features as well. But if you want to use es6 features such as `Promise` and `Map` then you need to target es6 or copy the definitions of what you need from the `libe.es6.d.ts`

Comment: Then, if we want to satisfy IE11,  `es6` objects; Map, Promise ,should be converted to `es5` objects. Thus, the target should be `es5` not `es6`. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know if IE11 supports `Map` and `Promise`. Check if it is supported, if so then all you need to do is copy the definitions from the `lib.es6.d.ts` so that it will compile when targeting es5. However, if they are not supported then you'll also need to polyfill them.

Comment: Its not the "target" that picks up the library but the "lib" should include the library for those objects. Look at @allenhwkim s answer. that solves the issue and is the right answer.

Comment: @RakeshKumarCherukuri Different targets come with different libs. If you choose to target `es6` you'll get the `es6` libs.

Comment: My point is that "target" is to specify what the *output* type should be (es5 in case of OP) and "lib" is to specify the libraries that webpack should use to compile the *source* code. Your answer/comment seems to make it sound as if the "target" is to specify the libs.

Comment: @RakeshKumarCherukuri You can specify other libs using the `--lib` flag as the other answer describes, but you can also target `es6`. Both are valid solutions, depends on what you want.

Comment: @RakeshKumarCherukuri not really. Target is used to chose how Typescript code is compiled. If you are targeting ES5 browsers, you should not specify ES6 target as the generated code may not work. The lib option is used to specify which library will be available at runtime. If you are polyfilling certain global objects (Map for example), then you should specify a library option which contains Map (ES6 for example).

Comment: Note that a possible confusion is the fact that changing the target also changes the the default lib option. from the doc: "If --lib is not specified a default list of libraries are injected. The default libraries injected are: 
► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost"

Comment: @cquezel No, there was no confusion at all. The answer was written **before** the `--lib` option was introduced.

Answer (score 43):

Just add:

```
 "lib": ["es6"] // means at least ES6
```

Don't change target.
Target is used to tell Typescript into which version of ECMAScript to compile your `.ts` files. Of course, you can change it, if the browser your application will be running in, will support that version of ECMAScript.

For example, I use `"target": "es5"` and `"lib": ["es6"]`.

---

**Another reason could be:**

That your `.ts` file is not under `"rootDir": "./YourFolder",`

Comment: Note that the `lib` option has [more than one library by default;](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) as they are, the examples above will drop other default libraries such as `DOM` and `ScriptHost` (and `DOM.Iterable` for ES6 targets).

Answer (score 14):

**If you are wondering why none of these fixes work** for you keep in mind -- if you specify the file to compile on the command line or package.json tsc will NOT read your tsconfig.json file and therefore have no effect. Instead specify the "files" and "outDir" in your tsconfig.json and one of the "lib" fixes will probably work for you. Then compile with only:

`tsc --sourcemaps`

Comment: Superb.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Winner, after reading all that this was the last post and was the one that made me go "oh duh" and fixed it.  Thanks

Comment: For typescript 3.7 this option looks like `--sourceMap`

Answer (score 10):

```
tsc index.ts --lib "es6"
```

If adding lib not working in tsconfig.json, using above command line option

Answer (score 8):

I had to install the core-js typings from npm to solve the issue

```
npm install @types/core-js
```

**explanation**:
The goal of @types npm packages is to obtain type definitions with npm. Using these type definitions is a **TypeScript 2.0** feature .

@types **replace** current tools such as **typings** and **tsd**, though these will continue to be supported for some time.

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44800490/9690407

```
npm install typings -g
typings install
```

is deprecated in npm 5.6.0!
Instead use the `npm install @types/core-js` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Since the answer directly to the OP has been answered already, I figured I would add what fixed it for me. My situation was slightly different in that I was not using WebPack and was getting these errors when trying to use tsc. The answer everyone else is giving (add "es6" to lib) did not resolve it for me. The problem for me was that I had v9.11.1 of node installed on my machine, but I had used npm to grab "@types/node", which got the most recent, v10+. Once I uninstalled that node typing and installed a specific v9 node typing file, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `node.js v10.16.3.` The problem for me was that the typescript compiler was ignoring my `tsconfig.json` file.

Three solutions worked for me:

1. Install ts-node and use that instead to compile and run the file
2. Do `tsc filename.ts --lib "es6", "dom"` when you compile the file
3. Install `@types/node` which will allow you to run `tsc filename.ts` without errors.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this error change the following properties in tsconfig.json file.

```
"lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "es5", 
      "es6"
    ],
"module": "es2015",
"target": "es6"
```

After that run following command in the terminal.

```
npm install @types/es6-shim
```

ERROR RESOLVED.

Answer (score 1):

In your tsconfig.json just change "target": "es5"  to "target": "es6"

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you only need to import map method in your ts file like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to install `@types/node`:

```sh
yarn add @types/node --dev
```

Or if you prefer npm:

```sh
npm install @types/node --dev
```

However, I suppose that if you plan to continue using "Map", "Set" or "Promise", it's good practice to include "es6" in the "lib" array in `tsconfig.json` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

for es6 use this

```
tsc filename.ts --lib es2015
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to run:

```
npm install typings -g
typings install
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: Note that **typings is deprecated** since TypeScript 2.0. Use @types instead.