# ng build error - Property 'requestMIDIAccess' does not exist

Tags: angular

I am trying to build an Angular2 project, using the Web Midi API.

When running`ng build`, I am not able to complete the process due to certain errors thrown, specifically:

```
Error in bail mode: [default] /Users/JmsToh/GitHub/web-editor/web-editor/src/app/midi.service.ts:43:22 
Property 'requestMIDIAccess' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

This comes from this part of the code:

```
if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess) {
  this.browserMidiCompatible = true;
  navigator.requestMIDIAccess({ sysex: false })
    .then(this.onMIDISuccess.bind(this), this.onMIDIReject.bind(this));
} else {
  alert("Platform not compatible");
}
```

The app runs fine on Chrome when running `ng serve`.Is there any way to get Angular2 to ignore the error when building?

Answer (score 10):

Add the [necessary type definitions](https://github.com/slavovojacek/adbrain-typescript-definitions/blob/master/webmidi/webmidi.d.ts) using:

```
npm install @types/webmidi
```

They should be automatically discovered after restarting `tsc`.

> note: If after installing the library you see errors "Cannot find name `Map`", see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39418293/399317).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I managed to remove this error by doing this instead:

`navigator["requestMIDIAccess"]`

Answer (score 3):

installing `@types/webmidi` allowed me to use the definitions and get vs code working, but it's not enought for compiling.

I was able to fix this issue by adding this compiler option in my tsconfig :
`"types": ["webmidi"]`

Comment: It work for me, for angular 6+ projects you have to add it into the `tsconfig.app.json` .

Answer (score 1):

It installed with the `npm install -s @types/webmidi` command and `Angular 7` could make use of it with the source code:

```
const requestMIDIAccess = navigator['requestMIDIAccess'];
if (requestMIDIAccess) {
  requestMIDIAccess().then(onMIDISuccess, onMIDIFailure);
  console.log('This browser supports WebMIDI!');
} else {
  console.log('WebMIDI is not supported in this browser.');
}
```