# for..of does not work with Map

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to loop through the map but nothing gets output in the console.

To be more precise I get following error in the transpiler:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

```
 let map = new Map([
  ["A", 1],
  ["B", 2],
  ["C", 3],
]);

for (let value of map.values()){
  console.log(value) ;
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module" : "commonjs",
    "target" : "es6" ,
    "noImplicitAny" : false ,
    "sourceMap" : false
  }
}
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: What "does not work"? Do you get an error? Where? What environment do you run the code in? What does the transpiled code look like?

Comment: No error . Like i stated nothing gets output in the console.

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39418293/1823841

Comment: @IvanIvanov Are you sure you are targeting `es6`? What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't seem to have anything to do with `for/of`.

Comment: @Saravana I am using Typescript Version 2.3.4  and I am targeting like : "target" : "es6"

Answer (score 1):

can you change your **tsconfig.json** to the conf below and try again?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],              
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny" : false 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  tsc cannot find my tsconfig.json. When I use :  `tsc -t ES6 app.ts` Transpilation went perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
map.forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value) ;
});
```