# how to report document issue on TypeScript website

Tags: git, typescript, github, pull-request

I found one document issue on TypeScript website, http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html, it's showing how to configure React, Webpack with TypeScript, but following the guide to configue will end up with an error:

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:815:38
TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'.`

Here someone figured out how to fix(add `"lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"]` in tsconfig.json), 
[webpack TS2304 Cannot find name 'Map', 'Set', 'Promise'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416691/webpack-ts2304-cannot-find-name-map-set-promise)
I'd like to report this issue to TypeScript website and get it fixed from the document.

i want to correct this documentation how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question does not appear to be about programming within the [scope defined by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/on-topic). What's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, so it may be necessary to reword the question to fit this site's scope after reviewing the community guidelines. Read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how you can ask a good question. :-)

Comment: If you would like to raise an issue for typescript, please do it in their official github repository. [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is already at least one [open pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/pull/827/files) for this and the TypeScript team is just too busy to properly maintain the handbook. :(

Comment: Thanks very much. @Matt