# Angular Issue - Cannot GET /

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

I am running an `ASP.NET Core` app with `Angular` in visual studio 2017. Unfortunately whenever I run the project, it shows the following message in the browser:

```
Cannot GET /
```

So few hours of googling ([Sample Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416691/webpack-ts2304-cannot-find-name-map-set-promise)), I tried the following, adding in the tsconfig.json file:

```
"lib": [ "es5", "es6", "es2017", "dom" ]
```

In my case, that was earlier as follows:

```
"lib": [ "es2017" ]
```

Though the project was built successfully, it had few errors as follows:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  ASP.NETCoreWithAngular  C:\Users\Amit's-PC\source\repos\ASP.NETCoreWithAngular\ASP.NETCoreWithAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts   48  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  ASP.NETCoreWithAngular  C:\Users\Amit's-PC\source\repos\ASP.NETCoreWithAngular\ASP.NETCoreWithAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts    24  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2585  (TS) 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  ASP.NETCoreWithAngular  C:\Users\Amit's-PC\source\repos\ASP.NETCoreWithAngular\ASP.NETCoreWithAngular\ClientApp\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts   58  Active
```

Anything that I missed here? Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the error messages you are getting it seems most likely your default configuration for `JavaScript` is `es5` or any other below `es2015`. Meaning you are trying to use `es2015` features and your compiler is now allowing you to. Check your IDE configs and make sure your `JavaScript` config is set to at least `es2015`

Comment: So you mean even it's running in visual studio 2017, I should include `es5` or `es2015`? Thanks for your suggestion and will try it @Hugo Noro.

Comment: Check the JavaScript configs on visual studio. It’s most likely defaulting to use es5 when transpiling TypeScript to JavaScript. And if that’s the case it means you won’t be able to use features from es2015 or es2017

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, I would think that you have a routing issue in the MVC part of your app.  You should endure that your default route is configured correctly.

The following article gives some useful guidance here.

https://knightcodes.com/angular2/2017/01/05/angular-2-routes-with-asp-net-mvc.html