# Cannot use Map in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, tsconfig

Throwing typedoc error while using Typescript `Map`. Find the below error.

> Property '***clear***' does not exist on type '**Map< string, number>**'.
>
> Property '***has***' does not exist on type '**Map< string, number>**'.
>
> Property '***set***' does not exist on type '**Map< number, string>**'.
>
> Property '***get***' does not exist on type '**Map< number, string>**'.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
        "es5",
        "es2015",
        "es2015.promise",
        "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
        "jasmine",
        "jasmine-ajax",
        "requirejs",
        "chai",
        "es6-promise"
    ]
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public",
    "coverage",
    "test-report"
],
"compileOnSave": false
}
```

How to resolve the error, is there any configuration need in tsconfig file?

**Note:** I have used `es2015` in `lib`, but it didn't resolve the error. And also it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack TS2304 Cannot find name 'Map', 'Set', 'Promise'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416691/webpack-ts2304-cannot-find-name-map-set-promise)

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky except he already has `"es2015",` in libs.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky mentioned link not solved my problem. I already did that suggestions.

Comment: Can you create reproducible example in codesandbox/stackblitz or something like that?

Comment: I am able to replicate this. If I switch to a ReadonlyMap the problem disappears. When I click through in VSCode to the Map, it lands at the MapConstructor and not the interface. If I run the typescript compiler, I get no issues. Is it possible that this is just an issue in VSCode for me? Maybe.