# Typescript error: Map.values() giving IterableIterator not Iterable

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript is giving me this error when I try to iterate over the value returned from `Map.values()` (where the Map has type <number,Foo>):

> error TS2495: Type 'IterableIterator<Foo>' is not an array type or a string type.

According to the ES6 [doc](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_maps-sets.html#_iterating-over-maps) `Map.values()` should return an `Iterable` not an IterableIterator and I should be able to use it in a for-of loop.

This works fine in `node`:

```
var data = [
  {id: 0},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 3}
];
var m = new Map(data.map(n => [n.id,n]));
for(var i of m.values()) { console.log(i) }
```

This gives the error from `tsc`:

```
interface Foo {
  id: number;
}
var data: Foo[] = [
  {id: 0},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2}
];
var m = new Map<number,Foo>(data.map(n => <[number,Foo]>[n.id,n]));
for(var i of m.values()) { console.log(i) }
```

I'm getting Map declarations from `@types/core-js@0.9.34` so I guess the issue is in this declaration??

**Other version & conf info:**

```
> tsc --version
Version 2.0.3
> cat tsconfig.json 
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't understanding some of the implicit stuff `tsc` is doing rel the `tsconfig.json`. Reading [tsconfig.json doc](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) made things clearer:

First, I was transpiling like this `tsc mytypescript.ts` which (stupidly) causes Typescript to silently ignore *tsconfig.json* file, which meant it was using the default ES5. But this was partially working because `tsc` was still finding the `core-js` declarations which contain declaration for ES6 things like Map, Iterable etc. That threw my debugging a bit.

Second, after getting Typescript to actually pick up my config, the config was wrong anyway. I don't actually need or want those declarations from `@types/core-js` (pretty sure). Yes, I'll use core-js as a polyfill in my project, but Typescript [comes with it's own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019750/2038383) declarations for ES6 stuff in `typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts`, and the ones in `@types/core-js` are old weird and crappy or something ...