# Running tsc generate errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

I am following 5-minute tutorial of typescript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html), and after running `tsc greeter.ts`, I am having few warnings/errors including `Duplicate identifier PropertyKey`. Since I am doing exactly what is mentioned in tutorial, I'm not sure why this is happening. Could anyone comment?

[`greeter.ts`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75YDA.png)

[Errors generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Pgq.png)

Comment: Do you mind including the full script you have come to write by this point?

Comment: It's exactly the same as in the link I provided.

Comment: Still, the full reference to the way it is written at your premise will be nothing but utterly helpful

Comment: Please have a look!

Comment: Perhaps try upgrading @types/core-js as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43098264/6872740