# How can I write this JS code using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to convert the following code into TypeScript. it is to create a key\value pairs

```
this.charUrls = item.urls.reduce(function (map, obj) {
  map[obj.type] = obj.url;
  return map;
}, {});
```

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
this.charUrls = item.urls.reduce(function (map, obj) { map[obj.type] = obj.url; return map; });
```

Comment: provide type to function arguments you can use 'any' type also like map: any, obj: any

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to define **item** variable. Try this,

```
let item:any;
this.charUrls = item.urls.reduce(function (map, obj) { map[obj.type] = obj.url; return map; });
```

Now it doesn't show any syntax errors in my IDE.

However, with further research I found out that ES6 Map is not supported by TypeScript natively now.

Refer this great answer thread, [ES6 Map in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript)