# how to process constants in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a react component like so:

```
const myComponent = ({constant}: Iprops) => (
  <div>
    {CONSTANTS[constant].property ? <showThis /> : null
  </div>
)
```

it's complaining that `element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'object' has no index signature`

how do I add `CONSTANTS` to my interface? I've tried

```
interface IProps {
    [CONSTANTS: any]: {
        constant: boolean;
    }
}
```

but obviously it doesn't like that. how can I declare the type of each key in my object?

thanks

Comment: What does CONSTANTS look like? Please, post the entire class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understanf the *shape* of the objects you actually need. But you can type an object with this syntax:

```
const CONSTANTS: { [key:string]: boolean } = {}
CONSTANTS["something1"] = false; // ok
CONSTANTS["something2"] = "Hey"; // not ok
```

It's a bit tricky as the key can actually [be either `string` or `number`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript/30019750#30019750) but the value type is properly enforced so you can still have more complex types there instead of a `boolean`.