# How do I declare the type of a value in a map in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble declaring the value of a value in a key-value pair of a map in TypeScript.

```
map: {
  key: someStruct
}
```

I would like to declare the type of `someStruct` while initializing it at the same time. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Map in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this, and assign it if you want also to some variable x

```typescript
let x = new Map([
        ["key", ["val1"]],
        ["key2", ["val2"]]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole object, but here's how you can do it.

This is your [Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
interface Struct {
   ...
}

interface Map {
   key: Struct
}
```

```js
const map: Map {
   key: someStruct
}
```

**or** if you don't have access to the whole object

```js
map: <Map>({
   key: someStruct
})

// or

map: {
   key: someStruct
} as Map
```