# Error getting when create Map with generic type?

Tags: typescript

```
abstract class Filter<T> { 

    protected filter = new Map<T>();

}
```

I get this error message:

```
No overload expects 1 type arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 0 or 2 type arguments
```

Why?

TypeScript 3.9.2

Full abstract class with all methods:

```
abstract class Filter<K, T> { 

    protected filterModel = new Map<K, T>();

    constructor(protected array: any, private model: T[]) {}

    abstract filter(): void;

    reset(): void { 
        this.filterModel.clear();
    }

    set(item: T) {
        this.filterModel.set("sss", item);
    }

    get(): T[] { 
        return this.model;
    }
}
```

Problem is in line: `this.filterModel.set("sss", item);`

**Using is:**

```
class FilterByOrderStatus extends Filter<string, FilterOrderStatus> { 

}
```

So, I try to fill filter model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify types for both key and value:

```
abstract class Filter<K, V> { 

    protected filter = new Map<K, V>();

}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30112075/2265497) related SO for more information

Comment: Thank you, how to set generic  value then in abstarct class?

`  set(item: T) {
        this.filterModel.set(item.type, item)
    }`

I mean typescript does not understan that property type is present in item. Also Ikey can be different, not only type