# Typechecking of Array Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript can declare strongly-typed [Array Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types)

But errors (from compiller) for the next snippet very strange. Could someone explain me error cases?

```typescript
interface SomeArray1 {
    [index: number]: string;    
}

var my1: SomeArray1;
my1["ab"] = 12;  // <-- why this line is OK?
my1["ab"] = "ab"; // <-- why this line is OK?
my1[12] = "ab";
my1[12] = 12; // <-- error

//-----------------------------

interface SomeArray2 {
    [index: string]: number;    
}

var my2: SomeArray2;

my2["ab"] = 12;
my2["ab"] = "ab"; // <-- error
my2[12] = "ab"; // <-- error
my2[12] = 12;

//-----------------------------

interface SomeArray3 {
    [index: string]: string;
}

var my3: SomeArray3;

my3["ab"] = 12; // <-- error
my3["ab"] = "ab";
my3[12] = "ab";
my3[12] = 12; // <-- error
```

Open sample in [playground](http://goo.gl/f33ut4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the documentation is confusing because the array type it describes does not constrain exclusively to an array. For example, the following would be allowed:

```
var my1: SomeArray1 = {};
```

What's being talked about, is more like a key-value/[dictionary-like type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13631557/188246) where, in the case of `SomeArray1`, the key is a `number` and the value is a `string`.

It would make more sense if it were instead defined as an array type with a string value constraint:

```
var my1: Array<string> = [];
```

Or even a type alias:

```
type SomeArray1 = Array<string>;
var my1: SomeArray1 = [];
```

In both these cases, assigning `{}` to the variable would not be allowed.

#### Value type constraint errors

All the errors are very similar. The main reason they are happening is because either there is a `string` value constraint and it is being assigned a `number` or vice-versa.

#### Index type constraint... no errors?

It is weird because the type constraint doesn't seem to be working on the index/key. I am certain this used to work. This is either a bug in the compiler or the typescript team decided to change this. I've opened up [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3150) to check.

---

And the response:

> We changed the behavior here because (at runtime) numbers are implicitly converted to strings during index operations. Basically, a string indexer is a "superset" of a number indexer.