# Declare a named type like a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, typescript

Can I create a type like a dictionary in typescript? For example the type of bar { `[id: string] : IPerson; }` which is a dictionary, how can I give it a name, let's say Dict and use that name instead of the whole `{ [id: string] : IPerson; }`?

```
class Foo {
  bar:{ [id: string] : IPerson; }
}
```

The data I receive from the server look like this

```
{
  "15" : { name: "James", age: 45},
  "34" : { name: "Mary", age: 22},
  ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Objects as Dictionary types as in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631557/typescript-objects-as-dictionary-types-as-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an `interface`:

```
interface Dict { 
  [id: string] : IPerson
}
class Foo {
  bar: Dict
}
```