# Strongly typed typescript collections

Tags: javascript, types, typescript

I'm trying to use "collections" (what is this paradigm actually called?) in typescript and have them strongly typed. In javascript I would write something like this.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var collection = {};

for(var x in array){
  collection['item-'+x] = x;
}
```

I have an object, and I add/remove elements using this `collection[name]` syntax.

This is great because I don't need to care about index's.
Now in typescript when I make an array I can declare it and give it a type.

```
let array: string[] = [];
```

How would this equate to this collection syntax, for example I have a collection like this.

```
var days = {};

days[moment().day('monday')] = new dayType('Monday');
days[moment().day('tuesday')] = new dayType('Tuesday');
```

This works great, but if I access my collection `days[moment().day('monday')].Name` I don't know if that is actually my dayType class or just an object with a `Name` property on it. And same thing with the property name. I can add `days['July']: = false;` just fine, even though that doesn't make sense in the context of my object.

Is this just a paradigm that doesn't fit with typeScript?

What is this paradigm called?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Objects as Dictionary types as in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631557/typescript-objects-as-dictionary-types-as-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you're using here looks like a dictionary. Try the following:

```
var days : { [key: string]: dayType; } = {};

days[moment().day('monday')] = new dayType('Monday');
```

You can also use an interface for shorthand:

```
interface dayDictionary {
    [key: string]: dayType;
}

var days: dayDictionary = { };
```

see: [TypeScript Objects as Dictionary types as in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631557/typescript-objects-as-dictionary-types-as-in-c-sharp#13631733)

Comment: Thanks! The interfaces will work perfectly, I'll have to use this from now on.