# Angular 2 Map<String, List<String>> is possible to create?

Tags: angular, typescript

is possible to create in angular 2  Map< String, List< String >>?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise please?

Comment: could you please explain a bit more of what you want to achieve. loop through some collection and return a value of type? < String, List< String >>. Or something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631557/typescript-objects-as-dictionary-types-as-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Map is ES6 feature and have nothing to do with Angular 2. You can create it using

```
var map = new Map<string, string[]>();
map.set('key', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
map.get('key');
```

You also need to set "module": "es6" in your tsconfig.json or use es6-shims definitions.

Comment: This doesn't work if I use AOT compilation. "ng serve --aot"